# react leaflet have a broken marker

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

I have imported Leaflet module along with some code to delete the Icon.

```js
import L from "leaflet";
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

delete L.Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl;

L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
  iconRetinaUrl: require("./images/marker-icon-2x.png"),
  iconUrl: require("./images/marker-icon.png"),
  shadowUrl: require("./images/marker-shadow.png"),
});
```

The Marker Icons reside in my image folder.
I also tried requiring directly:

```js
L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
  iconRetinaUrl: require("leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png"),
  iconUrl: require("leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png"),
  shadowUrl: require("leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png"),
});
```

But still I get a broken marker.

Comment: What is your build process? Are you using create-react-app? webpack? Does it work with an external url like: `https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png`? If it does then your build process may not be bundling the required resources. If it does not work with an externally hosted image your code is likely the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `create-react-app`, this should work with the Webpack configuration. You must put this code somewhere where it will execute before your `<Marker>` elements render like at the top of your `App.tsx` file:

```js
import L from 'leaflet';
import markerIcon2x from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png';
import markerIcon from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png';
import markerShadow from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png';

delete L.Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl;
L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
    iconUrl: markerIcon,
    iconRetinaUrl: markerIcon2x,
    shadowUrl: markerShadow,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

With [leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility](https://github.com/ghybs/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility) plugin, it should work without further code, provided that your build engine configuration is already setup to handle URL's in CSS:

`$ npm install leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility --save`

```js
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import 'leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility/dist/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility.webpack.css'; // Re-uses images from ~leaflet package
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility';
```

> Disclaimer: I am the author of that plugin